# Can I sync a single active directory user account?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My main question is in the title. This first part is to shed light on why I'm asking.

I'm writing a PowerShell script that will make it much easier for IT to give End Users a domain admin account to enter into UAC prompts for approved updates and software installs.This will not grant their account more power and they cannot run the script themselves.

Pseudo-code:

If Temp Admin account is Disabled {

1. Enable Temp Admin account
2. Reset the password to a randomly generated one
3. Display password to IT Tech (IT tech sends UN: Temp_Admin PW: w3ocxf8IP to End User)
4. Pause script - until Tech sees End User is finished
5. Reset the account to a new random password (does not display)
6. Disable the account

} else Sleep 30 seconds - start again

I have a couple questions before I implement it:

Is it possible to sync just the Temp Admin account (Not all of AD) across multiple DC's? We have offices all over the US so I'm worried that if the account is in use in TX and someone in NY tries to use it, things will get messed up if the account isn't synced.

Assuming this script is used a lot, am I just asking for AD or account errors by enabling/resetting/resetting/disabling the password and account this much?

I'm much more of a programmer than sysadmin so I don't know all of the details (repercussions) in AD.

Comment: It seems like a horrible idea to provide random users an Administrator account.  They could in theory, lock the real Administrators out, if they knew what they were doing.  *Your script compromises fundamentals of security.*

Comment: We won't be blindly giving them access at every request. We have a lot of field users that can get to VPN but IT can't always remote in over VPN. We can always see their screens through Skype for Business/Lync but we can't input creds. This script is to get around giving them the local admin creds, which don't change very often.

Comment: Also, I'm not granting the user's admin power. I'm giving them credentials to enter into the UAC box. Those credentials will then be reset so no one can access that account until the script is run again. The script will only be able to be run by admins. We will be watching their screen and approving their need for admin creds (mainly updating software or installing approved software in the field)

Comment: You said it yourself.  You don't know the repercussions of the script itself.  I cannot in good faith, as a System Administrator, help you write this script.  If they are not connected to the VPN, its not clear, how the script would communicate with your active domain in the first place anyways.

Comment: @Ramhound I never asked for help with the script. I provided the script as context for my System Administrator questions. So, as a system administrator, can you tell me if there is a way to sync a single AD account, rather than all of AD, across our DC's? And whether enabling and disabling the account + resetting the password twice per run could lead to weird account behavior (repercussions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sync a single user account in Active Directory, you can use the Cmdlet `Sync-ADObject`. To get all Domain Controllers you can use the Cmdlet `Get-ADGroupMember 'Domain Controllers'.` Putting them together looks like:

`Get-ADGroupMember 'Domain Controllers' | foreach {Sync-ADObject -object 'CN=test user, OU=TestOU, DC=company, DC=com' -source DC1 -Destination $_.name}`

You can add `;Write-Host "$_.name"` in between `$_.name` and the curly brace `}` to display its sync progress.

My other question was answered when I started playing with a working script. Resetting the password that often causes Active Directory to lock the account. To avoid this, use the Cmdlet:

`Unlock-ADAccount -Identity Test.User -ErrorAction Stop`

If something goes wrong with the unlock process, the error action will prevent the code from continuing.